# Binding objects to a Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, boundfield

I have three classes (domain, role and user). Domain and role are properties of the user class, like this:

```
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public Domain Domain { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
```

Domain and Role just have a ID property and a Name property.

I would like to bind a user list to my grid view, but showing the DomainName. Currently, I have my bound fields like this:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Domain.DomainName" SortExpression="UserDomain" ReadOnly="True" HeaderText="User Domain" />
```

But this isnt working, giving the fallowing error: `DataBinding: 'Yasur.Business.Entities.User' does not contain a property with the name 'DomainName'.`

What is the best way to do this?

Pedro Dusso

Comment: i dont think that is causing the error ,please post the code of 'User'
entity

Comment: but I already did, thats all my User class... just missed public class User { ... }

Comment: Post the code where you bind to the Gridview Datasource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to do two-way databinding with an object like this.  You can "Eval" the data if you use a TemplateField with syntax like this (not tested):

```
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# ((Domain)Eval("Domain")).DomainName %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```